# definition of tensor algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

In Loring Tu's *Differential Geometry: Connections, Curvature, and Characteristic Classes*, he defines the multiplication of tensor algebra as follows:

[image]

I'm amateur in tensor algebra. Here I am confused by the notation: Acutually $x\otimes y$ belongs to $T^k\otimes T^l$, but the author says $x\otimes y\in T^{k+l}(V)$.

I know $r(x\otimes y)=rx\otimes y$. But does $r\otimes x\otimes y=rx\otimes y$ hold where $r\in R$ and $x,y\in V$?

Thanks for help.

Comment: does the equality in your comment actually mean the canonical isomorphism?

Comment: $T^k(V)$ is the tensor product of $k$ copies of $V$ (not $T(V)$). Yes, equality means canonical isomorphism here. Given $x\otimes y\in T^k(V)\otimes T^l(V)$, it is a slight abuse of notation to say $x\otimes y\in T^{k+l}(V)$. Really, we have $\varphi(x\otimes y)\in T^{k+l}(V)$ where $\varphi:T^k(V)\otimes T^l(V)\to T^{k+l}(V)$ is the canonical isomorphism. However, to make notation easier, it's more convenient to say $x\otimes y\in T^{k+l}(V)$ since that's "essentially" what's happening here.

Comment: Thanks! I get it.